# ServiceStack.Text: problems with csv file which contains double quotes

Tags: c#, csv, quotes, servicestack-text

I'm using ServiceStack.Text library (V. 5.8.0) and experiencing problems while using it:

Data class (C#):

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public String PartID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "price")]
    public String Price { get; set; }
}
```

Program class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CsvConfig.ItemSeperatorString = ";";
        List<Item> Items = File.ReadAllText("/my/datafile.csv").FromCsv<List<Item>>();
        Debug.Print(Items.Dump());
    }
}
```

csv file:

```
id;price;foo
1;2"
1;2"
```

When running the MWE, console output is:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        price: "2""
1"
    }
]
```

This is pretty weird IMHO.

I modify the csv-file a bit:

```
id;price
1;2"
1;2"
```

Things are getting even worse, now an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception is thrown.

Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: The problem is the data, you have unbalanced double quotes.  In that case I wouldn't expect any particular behavior from a CSV parser.

Comment: You are right. I just read RFC 4180: If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote. If I stick to that spec, everything works fine.